# Viewing office 2010 documents in Internet Explorer

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010, moss, sharepoint-2003

I have office 2010 (32 bits) on windows 7 (64bits).

When viewing documents coming from our intranets (Moss 2010 or SharePoint 2003), the documents are opened inside the Office 2010 applications.

In the past with Office 2007, it was possible to view them directly inside IE.

I have tested to change the registry keys mentioned inside the MSDN article ID 927009 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927009) without great success.

Does someone know how to force office document to be viewed in IE?

Comment: What type of documents are they? .XLS and .DOC or .XLSX and .DOCX?

Comment: Every kind of Office documents, Regardless they come from 2010 or Office 2007.